# Copy multiple files with wildcard in bash

Tags: bash

Using Ubuntu 18.04. Say we have a file called `debug.log`. You can create a copy called `debug_BACKUP.log` with either of these commands:

```
cp debug.log debug_BACKUP.log
cp debug{,_BACKUP}.log
```

Alternatively, substitute `cp` with `mv` to rename the file.

Now suppose we have `debug1.log` and `debug2.log`. We would like to create copies called `debug1_BACKUP.log` and `debug2_BACKUP.log`. Is there a single command to achieve this?

When I tried either of the following:

```
cp debug*.log debug*_BACKUP.log
cp debug*{,_BACKUP}.log
```

the error is `cp: target 'debug*_BACKUP.log' is not a directory`.

Comment: It helps to think about what these expand to. When you run `cp debug{,_BACKUP}.log`, the shell rewrites it to `cp debug.log debug_BACKUP.log`. When you run `cp debug*{,_BACKUP}.log`, the shell rewrites it to `cp debug*.log debug*_BACKUP.log` (and then replaces `debug*.log` with a list of individual filenames matching that glob, and `debug*_BACKUP.log` likewise). Why the latter doesn't work should be plainly obvious.

Comment: Consider running `set -x` to make it more obvious what's happening / why the errors you're seeing are generated.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @CharlesDuffy, that makes sense.

Comment: You might want to search for the commands `mmv` and `mcp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace expansions are an instruction for the shell about how to rewrite your command before glob expansion takes place. They aren't passed to the command itself -- `cp` has no idea if a brace expansion was used. For that matter, `cp` doesn't even have any idea if a wildcard is used; when you run `cp *.txt dir/`, the shell generates an array of C strings corresponding to something like `cp foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt dir/` before running it.

This means that if you want to rewrite content after wildcard expansion takes place, you need to do it by hand.

```
for f in debug*.log; do
  [[ $f = *_BACKUP.log ]] && continue # skip things that are already backup files
  cp "$f" "${f%.log}_BACKUP.log"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few excellent bulk rename programs, including Perl based file-rename. You can achieve your bulk copy in 3 steps:

1. Copy the files to tmp sub folder
2. Perform bulk rename, moving the files back into the current folder
3. Remove the tmp folder

Comment: nice trick! rename's/before/after/g' * is good approach for the bulk rename. so total of 3 commands - copy, rename, move to same as originals